# Google Sheets API Run in Browser not Command Link

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have bee through the google sheets API guide and got everything working. When i run it on command line i get the data back from my spreadsheet that i am looking for.

The problem is that i want to use this data in my site but when i run the code in the browser i am told that it must be run in the command line.

Can any one tell me what i would need to change to be able to access this info via a growers rather than command line.

This is the guide i followed:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: That was just meant to serve as a demo on how to make PHP calls. First, you'd really have to know how to use PHP, integrating in browsers and all that. There's a [php demo code here](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/c747625bfe49625874bc) where he enabled PHP to run from CLI to browser.  Then, check the [Sheets API guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) to use the REST calls. There's also a bunch of samples you can use as reference in [Sheet Samples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/).

Answer (score 0):

The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command-line application. For information on how to perform authorization in a web application, see [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app).

Answer (score -1):

Delete below code, that's it.

```
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
```